# The source was not found but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs:Security

Tags: asp.net, event-log, bizagi

I am trying to run an application of Bizagi platform called Personal Loans Request. Everything goes fine until at one point when I click on a "Next" button it shows me this error:
*Unable to process the case: The source was not found but some or all event logs could not be searched. To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs:Security*

I have done researches all the day. All this researches lead to almost the same :
Add to Network Service the permission to read in Event Logs Security. 
I did this but the same problem occures.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this works for your scenario, but I ran this in PowerShell and it worked for 
me when I had a similar error.

```
[system.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("SourceName", "Application")
```

Replace "Application" with the name of the application that's trying to write to the log. "SourceName" can be any word that's not already a registered source name.

I found this method, and others, in an answer from [JMarsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67038/jmarsch), here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/774713/120966

Answer (score 1):

A work around for this is to run Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: This is not a right solution, especially for end-user.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub - It may not be the right solution for an end-user, but it solved the problem I was having running from Visual Studio, so I'm glad Brian Wood posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application is attempting to write to the windows logs, but it's being shutdown by Windows security. Make sure you're running your application in administrator mode, which should allow the program access to search the registry to see if it needs to create a new log source.