# ASP.NET exceptions not showing in Application EventLog

Tags: asp.net

On my Windows 2008 R2 servers, every uncaught ASP.NET exception generates an event that shows in the Windows Application Eventlog.

On my Windows 2012 servers, none of them do.

Is there anything I can do, purely in configuration (not adding code to my application), to make my Windows 2012 servers show these exceptions?

**EDIT**: To clarify, my app does not write to the eventlog from code. The problem is that I expect when an app crashes, **IIS** will write to the eventlog. That's not happening.

The problem still exists to this day. I cannot depend on IIS consistently writing to the eventlog when an app crashes. I usually do get an eventlog entry when rapidfail protection kicks in and the pool is disabled. But the individual error messages that should be in the eventlog when the app crashes -- sometimes there, sometimes not.

Comment: Does the account the run the IIS app pool have the right permissions to write to the event log?

Comment: On the 2012 server it is running as ApplicationPoolIdentity. Not sufficient?

Answer (score -1):

your problem is most likely permissions related. Please have a look at this thread here and mark this as answered if you are happy with the resolution

[Writing to an event log in ASP.NET on Windows Server 2008 IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712203/writing-to-an-event-log-in-asp-net-on-windows-server-2008-iis7)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why I accepted this answer now. My app doesn't (didn't) have code to write to the eventlog.

Comment: Answer unaccepted.