# EventLog Permission MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have made an MVC application where I use following line in one of the method:

```
EventLog ev = new EventLog();
```

It works fine on local but when I tried to run it on server, this line gave me following error:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Diagnostics.EventLogPermission,System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I am not able to understand the issue, can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712203/writing-to-an-event-log-in-asp-net-on-windows-server-2008-iis7.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to simply ask for the correct security permissions prior to using the Event log, like so:

```
  EventLogPermission eventLogPermission = new EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, ".");
  eventLogPermission.PermitOnly();
```

See here:
[support.microsoft.com bug article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/918122)